# Safari 11 mediaElement['srcObject'] = mediaStream throws Type Error

Tags: safari, webrtc, mediaelement, mediastream, rtcmulticonnection

I am trying to implement WebRTC using this library ([RTCMulticonnection](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/dist/RTCMultiConnection.js)) and am encountering a `Type Error` when trying to set the 'srcObject' on the video mediaElement in Safari Tech Preview 11.

**Relevant code:**

```
if (isSafari) {

    //I've tried the 4 ways below to set the srcObject but all cause a Type Error

      // mediaElement['srcObject'] = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); throws type error
      // mediaElement['srcObject'] = stream; throws type error
      // mediaElement['src'] = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      // mediaElement.srcObject = stream; // throws type error
}
```

When I print `mediaElement`, I get: `<video></video>`

When I print `stream`, I get a `MediaStream` object.

```
MediaStream {streamid: "722cfcc7-0687-4265-b266-e81b2abf8398", idInstance: "{\"audio\":{\"mandatory\":{},\"optional\":[{\"bandwidth\":…\":[{\"bandwidth\":4194304},{\"facingMode\":\"user\"}]}}", isVideo: 1, isAudio: false, type: "local", …}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Type error
[Error] No message (2)
TypeError: Type error — RTCMultiConnection.js:4089
Object audio: {mandatory: {}, optional: [{bandwidth: 1048576}]}
    video: {mandatory: {}, optional: [{bandwidth: 4194304}, {facingMode: "user"}]}

Object Prototype
    onMediaError (RTCMultiConnection.js:5215)
    onLocalMediaError (RTCMultiConnection.js:806)
    onLocalMediaError (RTCMultiConnection.js:4995)
    (anonymous function) (RTCMultiConnection.js:3365)
    promiseReactionJob
```

The `Type Error` is caught in this `then/catch`:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(options.localMediaConstraints).then(function(stream) {
      stream.streamid = stream.streamid || stream.id || getRandomString();
      stream.idInstance = idInstance;
      streaming(stream);
  }).catch(function(error) {
      options.onLocalMediaError(error, options.localMediaConstraints             });
```